# JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both java and libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: java, java-8

While building my project in Android Studio 2.1.1 I got this error:

> Error:objc[2604]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I've seen other questions like this one but they all say it was fixed in some version of Java7.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Mac OS X. have setted CompileOptions in gradle file to 1.7, but no changes:

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

Answer (score 3):

The following steps solved my issue:

Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.. > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: This solved my issue only temporary. After few builds I get the errors again. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

The Android team has stated that this is a known issue with no negative effects. See [AOSP issue 2049707](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204797) which references [JDK issue 8022291](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022291)